# clicking the button toggle list(ul) popover using bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have button and  ul list in my html .Initially my ul list is initially  hide state .Can anybody tell how to toggle ul list(hide and show) using bootstrap popover and provide position or dataplacement

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title">Popover</button>
```



```
<div id="myPopover" class="hide">
    This is a popover list:
    <ul>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        <li>List item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since using html implies overriding the `title` attribute, there needs to be a way to tie the content to an html element.

Here I'm using another `data-` attribute (`data-htmlcontent`) that contains the id of a hidden element's inner HTML that you would like to see in a tooltip. Note the use of the `html:true` in the options object

This is one way to accomplish what you need:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      let contentID = $(this).data('htmlcontent');
      return $(contentID).html();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-htmlcontent='#myPopoverContent' >Popover</button>

<div id="myPopoverContent" hidden>
  This is a popover list:
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```